# How can Locale.setDefault(new Locale ("en", "US")) be changed at runtime?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, internationalization, locale

I keep looking for the answer on how to reset/change the `Locale` of a Java (Spring) web application once it's set via the `Locale.setDefault(new Locale ("en", "US"))`. Can someone please help me because it's frustrating seeing that after I set the Locale in my web app, I can't change it by simply calling `Locale.setDefault(new Locale ("newLang", "newCountry"))`.

Is the locale being cached on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Locale.setDefault` is a global thing. If you have two users that need to use different locales that won't work out.

You should probably put the locale in the `HttpServletRequest.getSession()`.

After we did the global setDefault it even switched the language and logging of our application server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try subclassing the Velocity ResourceTool.java and return locale based on client's request. Hopefully that will work. 

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The `Locale.setDefault(...)` has no restrictions as to when or how many times it can be called. The change can be prevented by the security manager, but I assume it's not your case, since you don't mention any exceptions (just in case, though, verify if you don't hide `SecurityException` in a try-catch block).

Other reason why you might observe such behaviour, is that perhaps your application obtains the default locale only once, caches it and uses forever?

Comment: It's really the Apache Velocity ResourceTool class that uses the Default Locale set and then uses that to render the Velocity templates. Udo Held above pointed out that the setDefaultLocale() will affect the whole app. I may need to subclass ResourceTool.java and return the locale based on the session request.

Answer (score -3):

```
public String arabic_lng() {
    // Add event code here...
        FacesContext ha_faces= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Locale ar = new Locale("ar","SA");
       Locale.setDefault(new Locale ("ar","SA"));
        System.out.println(ar.getDisplayName(ar));
        ha_faces.getViewRoot().setLocale(ar);



    return null ;
}

public String eng_lng() {
    // Add event code here...

    FacesContext ha_faces= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Locale en = new Locale("en", "US");
    System.out.println(en.getDisplayName(en));
    ha_faces.getViewRoot().setLocale(en);
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale ("en", "US"));

    return null ;
}
```

Comment: It's better if you can add some words instead of post just source code.